# From Xaml-String to Wpf-Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I keep having problems with creating a Wpf-Window from a Xaml-String.

**What works:**
I have a Server running which can receive Strings from remote Clients. (That is not complicated and works perfectly)

**What doesn’t work:**
Sometimes the Server receives a String with the content of a Xaml-File. Know I want to create a window dynamically with all the content specified in the Xaml-String.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
var window = XamlReader.Parse(SomeXamlString) as Window;
```

Comment: But this only works if there is no Event-Handling! When I add a ButtonClick-Event then I get following error:    

'Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'button1_Click' [...]
My plan was to replace the x:Class Tag in the Xaml-String so that it looks like this: x:Class="WpfWindowFromString.MyWindow" so that I can use MyWindow.Connect(int connectionId, object target) to create the right delegates for the event handling. But then I get following error:    
       
'Specified class name 'WpfWindowFromString.MyWindow' doesn't match actual root instance type 'System.Windows.Window'.

Comment: indeed. this method can only be used for LOOSE xaml. however, u can gave name to elements using the Name Property (not x:Name) and then do btn = window.FindControl("MyButton"); btn.Click += ...